# Custom instance provider for Ninject factory

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I've got the following two interfaces:

```
public interface ILogger {}
public interface ILoggerFactory {}
```

The ILoggerFactory contains a method `GetLogger` that takes the `Type` of the calling class as a parameter and returns an logger instance implementing `ILogger`. Now I would like to declare a instance provider that automatically wires up everything so I can inject my logger directly into a class. I tried it the following way:

```
Kernel.Bind<ILoggerFactory>().To<MyCustomLoggerFactory>();
Kernel.Bind<ILogger>().ToFactory(() => new LoggerFactoryInstanceProvider());

public class LoggerFactoryInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider {

    protected override ... // what goes here?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
Kernel.Bind<ILoggerFactory>().To<MyCustomLoggerFactory>();
IBindingRoot.Bind<ILogger>().ToProvider<LoggerProvider>();

public class LoggerProvider : Provider<ILogger> {

    private readonly ILoggerFactory factory;

    public LoggerProvider(ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
         this.factory = factory;
    }

    protected override T CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
         return this.factory.GetLogger(context.Request.ParentRequest.Service);
    }
}
```

If you have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(ILogger logger) { }

}
```

then ninject will use the provider to create an `ILogger` instance. The provider will return `ILoggerFactory.GetLogger(typeof(Foo))`.